# Adding email recipients based on a text in email body

Tags: vba, outlook

Example email body:

> Smart Quote Request SQ-1234567 submitted from BRENNAN Group Ltd for
> YOURTOWN has been reviewed and quoted by HP.

If the e-mail body contains `BRENNAN`, I want to do this when I click the Forward button:

- Add email1@email.com & email2@email.com in the "To" field
- Add email3@email.com & email4@email.com in the "Cc" field

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. It seems you need to handle the [Forward](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.forward(even)) event of the `MailItem` class which is fired when the user selects the `Forward` action for an item, or when the `Forward` method is called for the item. The new item being forwarded is provided as the argument to the event handler. For example:

```
Public WithEvents myItem As Outlook.MailItem 
 
 
 
Public Sub Initialize_Handler() 
 
 Set myItem = Application.ActiveInspector.CurrentItem 
 
End Sub 
 
 
 
Private Sub myItem_Forward(ByVal Forward As Object, Cancel As Boolean)  
 Forward.Cc = "email3@email.com; email4@email.com" 
End Sub
```

Also you can use the [MailItem.Recipients](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.recipients) property which returns a `Recipients` collection that represents all the recipients for the Outlook item. The [Recipients.Add](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.recipients.add) method creates a new recipient in the `Recipients` collection. For example, to add CC recipient you can use the following code:

```
Dim myRecipient as Outlook.Recipient
Set myRecipient = myItem.Recipients.Add ("email3@email.com") 
myRecipient.Type = olCC
```

Finally, if you are new to VBA, you may find the following pages helpful:

- [Getting started with VBA in Office](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/library-reference/concepts/getting-started-with-vba-in-office)
- [Automating Outlook from a Visual Basic Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/automating-outlook-from-a-visual-basic-application)